# Раскрывающийся элементы списка

Tags: android

Здравствуйте.
Мне нужно сделать в панели navigation drawer вот такой раскрывающийся список (фоотографии -> мои фото, фотосейф):

[image]

Я достаточно недавно начал изучение разработки под android, не могли бы подсказать или написать пару ссылок на такие реализации.
В принципе тут не сложно, при клике на определенный item меняется свойство visibility, но хотелось бы посмотреть примеры, на основе listview.

UPD

Посмотрите код что я написал пожалуйста, и оцените его, я еще новичок и мне нужно знать что правильно я сделал, а что нет.
Для удобства, я поместил все настройки этого меню в xml ресурс, и читаю оттуда, что бы потом не лазить в код, а исправлять только этот ресурс.
Поэтому получился такой "грязный" адаптер, из-за возни с ресурсами...

Адаптер:

```
public class ExpListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

protected ArrayList<Map<String, String>> mParents = new ArrayList<>();
protected ArrayList<ArrayList<Map<String, String>>> mChilds = new ArrayList<>();
private Context mContext;
private int mResParent;
private int mResChild;

public ExpListAdapter (Context context, Integer resource, int resParent, int resChild) {
    mContext = context;
    mResParent = resParent;
    mResChild = resChild;
    Resources res = mContext.getResources();
    String string_res = res.getResourceEntryName(resource);
    String[] parents = res.getStringArray(resource);
    int idIcons = res.getIdentifier("icons_" + string_res, "array", mContext.getPackageName());
    String[] icons = res.getStringArray(idIcons);
    for (int i = 0; i < parents.length; i++) {
        HashMap<String, String> parent = new HashMap<String, String>();
        parent.put("title", parents[i]);
        parent.put("icon", getIconName(icons[i]));
        mParents.add(parent);
        String name = "drop_"+i+"_"+string_res;
        int idChilds = res.getIdentifier(name, "array", mContext.getPackageName());
        ArrayList<Map<String, String>> childItem = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
        if (idChilds != 0) {
            String[] childs = res.getStringArray(idChilds);
            int idChildIcons = res.getIdentifier("icons_" + name, "array", mContext.getPackageName());
            String[] childIcons = res.getStringArray(idChildIcons);
            for (int j = 0; j < childs.length; j++) {
                HashMap<String, String> child = new HashMap<String, String>();
                child.put("title", childs[j]);
                child.put("icon", getIconName(childIcons[j]));
                childItem.add(child);
            }
        }
        mChilds.add(childItem);
    }
}

protected String getIconName(String icon) {
    String icon_name;
    String[] tmp_icon = icon.split("/");
    icon_name = tmp_icon[tmp_icon.length-1];
    int i = icon_name.lastIndexOf('.');
    if (i != -1) {
        icon_name = icon_name.substring(0, i);
    }
    return icon_name;
}

@Override
public int getGroupCount() {
    return mParents.size();
}

@Override
public int getChildrenCount(int parentPosition) {
    return mChilds.get(parentPosition).size();
}

@Override
public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
    return mParents.get(groupPosition);
}

@Override
public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return mChilds.get(groupPosition).get(childPosition);
}

@Override
public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
    return groupPosition;
}

@Override
public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return childPosition;
}

@Override
public boolean hasStableIds() {
    return true;
}

@Override
public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView,
                         ViewGroup parent) {
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(mResParent, null);
    }
    Resources res = mContext.getResources();
    int idIcon = res.getIdentifier(mParents.get(groupPosition).get("icon"), "drawable", mContext.getPackageName());
    TextView title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);
    ImageView icon = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.icon);
    title.setText(mParents.get(groupPosition).get("title"));
    icon.setImageDrawable(res.getDrawable(idIcon));
    return convertView;
}

@Override
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild,
                         View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(mResChild, null);
    }
    Resources res = mContext.getResources();
    int idIcon = res.getIdentifier(mChilds.get(groupPosition).get(childPosition).get("icon"),
            "drawable", mContext.getPackageName());
    TextView title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);
    ImageView icon = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.icon);
    title.setText(mChilds.get(groupPosition).get(childPosition).get("title"));
    icon.setImageDrawable(res.getDrawable(idIcon));
    return convertView;
}

@Override
public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return true;
}
```

}

XMl ресурс:

```
<resources>
<string-array name="menu_drawer">
    <item>Итем 1</item>
    <item>Итем 2</item>
    <item>Итем 3</item>
</string-array>

<string-array name="drop_1_menu_drawer">
    <item>Подитем 1</item>
    <item>Подитем 2</item>
    <item>Подитем 3</item>
</string-array>

<string-array name="icons_menu_drawer">
    <item>@drawable/icon1</item>
    <item>@drawable/icon2</item>
    <item>@drawable/icon3</item>
</string-array>

<string-array name="icons_drop_1_menu_drawer">
    <item>@drawable/icon4</item>
    <item>@drawable/icon5</item>
    <item>@drawable/icon6</item>
</string-array>
```

Comment: http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/86-urok-45-spisok-derevo-expandablelistview         

  
http://habrahabr.ru/post/147546/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для решения данной задачи лучше подойдет `ExpandableListView`, который, как мне кажется, и используется в приведенном скриншоте.

> не могли бы подсказать или написать пару ссылок на такие реализации

Для начала посоветовал бы Вам, освоить сам ExpandableListView, а далее уже прикрутить его к NavigationDrawer не должно составить труда.

Про основы можете почитать [тут](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/views/expandablelistview.php), [тут](http://habrahabr.ru/post/147546/) и [тут](http://theopentutorials.com/tutorials/android/listview/android-expandable-list-view-example/).

А вот [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21165586/4728929) есть пример пример использования ExpandableListView в NavigationDrawer.

Comment: Посмотрите пожалуйста код что я написал, и оцените его, я еще новичок и мне нужно знать что правильно я сделал, а что нет

Comment: @wpbloger да вроде бы все норм, проверка `convertView ` на `null` есть, может быть `Resources res = mContext.getResources();` переменную можно вынести, что бы она не создавалась каждый раз при вызове `getChildView` и `getGroupView`, еще может прикрутить `ViewHolder` было бы

Comment: Да и правда, можно вынести ресурсы в поле, и не создавать каждый раз, а вот про ViewHolder не знал, сейчас посмотрел, говорят что он хорош когда много элементов, а тут у меня максимум штук 15 будет. Не подскажите где можно почитать про такие вот хаки, типа как ViewHolder, ресурс или книжку какую, что бы укрепить знания так сказать.

Comment: @wpbloger действительно, это же меню, тут элементов не много, следовательно вся эта оптимизация никакого ощутимого положительного эффекта не принесет, так что можете особо не париться)но на будущее все таки может пригодиться